# Delete specific row in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
            col1     col2     col3 
1             0        1       5
2             0        3       0
3             5        4       5
4             5        5       0
5             5        3       7
```

I want to delete every row that contains the string '0' in column 'col1' and '5' in column 'col3'. How can I accomplish this in R?

```
            col1     col2     col3 
2             0        3       0
3             5        4       5
4             5        5       0
5             5        3       7
```

Thank U.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at some basic R introduction, e.g. [Quick R](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) or [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

Comment: beginneR: good suggestion, but I don't see the problem with a question like this one - SO is a compendium of clear questions and answers. That they can be found elsewhere matters not a bit.  Sure, it'd be nice to see more research effort, though it really wouldn't have improved the clarity of the question.  R solves this sort of thing in a way that is not intuitive for new users.

Comment: @Argalatyr, fair enough. My opinion is that new R users should at least start learning very basic operations like subsetting by reading an introduction/basic tutorial before asking here (or at least show that they've tried something and got stuck).

Comment: beginneR and Argalatyr Thank u for your recommend but I research answer for my question so I think post question. However I hope u recommend use R program for new R users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data set called `df`

```
df[!(df$col1 == 0 & df$col3 == 5), ]

##   col1 col2 col3
## 2    0    3    0
## 3    5    4    5
## 4    5    5    0
## 5    5    3    7
```